# Entropy of the Uniform Mixture of Discrete Probability Distribtuions

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables, information-theory, entropy

Consider the following inequality:
\begin{equation}
H\left(\frac{1}{3}p_{1} + \frac{1}{3}p_{2} + \frac{1}{3}p_{3}\right) \geq H(0.5p_{1} + 0.5p_{2})
\end{equation}
where H(.) denotes the Shannon entropy of the probability distribution in its argument. Does this hold for discrete probability distributions $p_{1}, p_{2}$ and $p_{3}$ over the same alphabet such that the distributions are permutations of each other (i.e. such that $H(p_{1}) = H(p_{2}) = H(p_{3})$)? Furthermore, can this be generalised to say that the entropy of a larger uniform mixture of permutations of discrete probability distributions always increases (or maintains) the entropy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider domain $\{0,1\}$, and trivial point masses $p_1,p_2,p_3$ as follows.
$
p_1(0)=p_3(0)=1
$
and
$p_2(1)=1$. Then
$$
H\left(\frac{p_1+p_2}{2}\right) = h_2(1/2) =\log 2
$$
but
$$
H\left(\frac{p_1+p_2+p_3}{3}\right) = H\left(\frac{2}{3}p_1+\frac{1}{3}p_2\right) = h_2(1/3) < \log 2
$$
so your inequality does not hold, even for a domain of size $2$.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. This has made me wonder what happens if we enforce that the distributions be *distinct* permutations of each other.

Comment: @SamuelLiebana I am pretty sure this still won't work -- replace domain size $2$ by domain size $n\geq 3$, and instead of point masses have $p_1,p_2,p_3$ be almost as they currently are, but with $1-\varepsilon$ mass instead of 1 (and $\varepsilon \ll 1$ mass each on a second point). You can get 3 distinct permutations, but still have $p_1(0)=p_3(0)=1-\varepsilon$ and $p_2(1)=1-\varepsilon$, which for a small enough $\varepsilon>0$ will still give a counterexample.

Comment: You may instead ask that the support of $p_1,p_2,p_3$ be disjoint, but now it's becoming a very restrictive constraint (I'm not sure the original inequality holds in this case, but it may).

Comment: Yes that is quite a restrictive constraint. Thank you very much that has been very helpful!

Comment: No worries. Sorry not to have better news :)